# Is it possible to rotate a logcat file with just one file (rotates on itself)?

Tags: android, logcat

```
singleton.exec("logcat -v long -f " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath() + " -r 5000 -n 1");
```

I want 1 file that overwrites itself after it has reached 5000 bytes. I swear this exact code actually worked for me at one point but it was a few days ago :/ Not sure if I was seeing things lol. Now when I use this code, I get two files:

somefile.txt and
somefile.txt.1

when one fills, the other starts being overwritten. But I want this:

somefile.txt

which keeps overwriting itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a logcat option to truncate and copy the file instead of moving to a new file. There is also a rotation number option on how many backup file stored (the files ending with number), I think that's what you are looking for.

I'm on my phone right now, sorry can't give more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
singleton.exec("logcat -v long -f " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath() + " -r 5 -n 1");
```

See if that works for you. The **-r** takes **kb** and not **bytes**. Make sure the app has permission to write the file to the location.

Comment: I know it's kb. I actually want 5000kb. Which would be 5 mega bytes of log. That's just what I was instructed to do.